# How to fix "The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version" error?

Tags: amazon-sqs, http-status-code-400, localstack

I try to use LocalStack and create aws sqs queues locally.
Here is my terminal:
[image]

[image]

I create queues using this command `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name activitiesQueue`

Then list queue using this command `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs list-queues` Then created queues are displayed.

I try to consume queue messages using command or try to start node.js server:

Command:`aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566  sqs send-message --region us-east-1  --queue-url "http://localhost:4566/000000000000/activitiesQueue"  --message-body '{"command":["do-something"]}'`

then the following error occurred.

> **An error occurred (AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue) when calling the SendMessage operation: The specified queue does not exist
> for this wsdl version**
> [image]

I also set aws credentials:

> path:
> C:\Users\user.aws

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: You might look at this answer once: - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77046729/12326605

Comment: They're looking for a localstack specific answer @ArpitJain the answer regarding region mismatch is the more likely solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the LocalStack default region using `LocalStack config show` command.
The default region was "ap-southeast-1". Then I created a queue with the aws region in the config.js file.

Region mismatch was the cause of the error.

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name activitiesQueue --region us-east-1
```

Then using `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs list-queues --region us-east-1` command I checked all the created queues in the LocalStack.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me a lot of hassle!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that my solution was helpful to you and saved you some hassle. Happy coding!